# Emacs: custom function and keybinding for commenting out line

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I have been trying out stuff and looking at other answers for several hours now and I cannot figure out how to make custom functions and keybindings work... and it is absolutely infuriating.

For the purposes of testing I wrote this function

```
(defun my/cmmt ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (move-beginning-of-line 1)
  (comment-region 1))

(global-set-key (kbd "\C-o")
        'my/cmmt)
```

There are 2 issues, I want it bind this to `C-m` but then I get an error:

`symbol's value as variable is void: C-m`

What does that mean?

And also, all it ever does is move the cursor to the beginning of the line, but not comment it out. Why?

## Edit

```
(defun my/cmmt ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (comment-region
   (line-beginning-position)
   (line-end-position)
          )
  )

(global-set-key (kbd "C-o")
        'my/cmmt)
```

Now the error is:

`symbol's function definition is void: \,`

Comment: `C-h f comment-region`. `C-h f kbd`. Consider also consulting the manual "*An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp*", available within Emacs using `C-h i`. And the Emacs manual, node [Key Bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html). And consider trying one thing at a time - here you had one problem with `comment-region` and another problem with `kbd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(kbd "C-o")` not `(kbd "\C-o")`

You're confusing two methods of specifying keys -- `(kbd "C-o")` and `"\C-o"` are equivalent.

I recommend using `kbd`, and simply typing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>*keys*</kbd> to learn what to pass to `kbd` to specify the key sequence <kbd>*keys*</kbd>. e.g.: when you type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd> Emacs tells you that `C-o` is the representation of that key sequence, so `"C-o"` is what you must pass to `kbd`.

The reason the commenting doesn't work is because `(comment-region 1)` isn't valid. You should be seeing an error. It takes *two* required arguments. See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `comment-region` for details.

Comment: the help text for `comment-region` does not tell me how I can define `BEG` and `END` though.

Comment: Well that's up to you. However I guess what you wanted was `(comment-region (point) (line-end-position))`.

Comment: Ah, I see. It still doesn't work though. Updated the question.

Comment: Sry, I just screwed up the copy paste. Now the entire `global-set-key` form is in. So, that was not it.

Comment: restarting emacs made it work. But what about the `C-m` binding not working? Why can't I assign whatever binding i want?

Comment: For `C-m` specifically, be aware that that is the same thing as `RET`, so you probably won't *want* to bind anything to that. However keybinding *in general* is a complicated and many-layered subject, and certainly out of scope for this discussion. I highly recommend reading http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/